# Warning: Missing argument 2 for addProfile()

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are already quite a few articles on SE about "Warning: Missing argument 2 for" questions, although I couldn't really seem to find an answer (even after looking over all of the other questions several times).

First Error Set: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTySO.png

Second Error Set: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDwxm.png

(I tried posting as SE images, but since I'm new it wouldn't let me)

Those are the two errors I'm currently getting 20 times (I have 20 different fields for the database, it's a "profile" section).

I've spent the better half of two hours trying to figure out why it's not working but I'm clueless.

addProfile.php :

```
<?php
include('../includes/functions.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['profile_name'])) {
            addProfile($_POST['profile_name']);
        } else {
            echo "Please Enter A Profile Name!";
            include('manage_settings.php');
        }
        if(isset($_POST['profile_description'])) {
            addProfile($_POST['profile_description']);
        } else {
            echo "Please Enter A Profile Description!";
            include('manage_settings.php');
        }
            if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['first_name']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['last_name']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['company'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['company']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['office_phone'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['office_phone']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['cell_phone'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['cell_phone']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['fax_num'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['fax_num']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['email_addr'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['email_addr']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['website'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['website']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['motto'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['motto']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['street_addr'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['street_addr']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['city'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['city']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['state'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['state']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['zip'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['zip']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['country'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['country']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['facebook_url'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['facebook_url']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['places_url'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['places_url']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['twitter_url'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['twitter_url']);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['linkedin_url'])) {
                addProfile($_POST['linkedin_url']);
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: manage_settings.php");
    }
?>
```

functions.php :

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

function getProfiles() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM global_profiles") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        echo "<center><h3><b><u>No Profiles Currently Available</u></b></h3></center>";
    } else {
        while($profile = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" /></td><td>" . $profile['profile_name'] . "</td><td><a href=\"#\" title=\"title\">Coming Soon</a></td><td>" . $profile['profile_description'] . "</td><td>" . $profile['pid'] . "</td><td><a href=\"edit.php?pid=" . $profile['pid'] . "\" title=\"Edit\"><img src=\"images/pencil.png\" alt=\"Edit\" /></a> <a href=\"delete.php?pid=" . $profile['pid'] . "\" title=\"Delete\"><img src=\"images/cross.png\" alt=\"Delete\" /></a> <a href=\"duplicate.php?pid=" . $profile['pid'] . "\" title=\"Duplicate\"><img src=\"images/hammer_screwdriver.png\" alt=\"Duplicate\" /></a></td></tr>";
        }
    }
}

function deleteProfile($pid) {
    $pid = (int) $pid;
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM global_profiles WHERE pid = '$pid'") or die(mysql_error());
    header("Location: manage_settings.php");
}

function addProfile($pid, $profile_name, $profile_description, $first_name, $last_name, $company, $office_phone, $cell_phone, $fax_num, $email_addr, $website, $motto, $city, $state, $zip, $country, $facebook_url, $places_url, $twitter_url, $linkedin_url) {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO global_profiles VALUES(null,'$profile_name','$profile_description','$first_name','$last_name','$company','$office_phone','$cell_phone','$fax_num','$email_addr','$website','$motto','$city','$state','$zip','$country','$facebook_url','$places_url','$twitter_url','$linkedin_url')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is basically "save" new information to my database. I've been able to manually add it into the database via phpMyAdmin, then display the information inside my admin area.

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: You say "this function takes 20+ parameters" and then pass only one. What do you really expect to happen?

Comment: That's an SQL injection waiting to happen.

Comment: As DCoder says, you only pass one parameter.

If you want to make the other ones optional, set some sandard-value to them.

for example:

instead of foo(x,y,z) use foo(x, y="lol",z="hehehe")
I would require atleast one parameter in a set.
or something.

But you should consider using a class instead. That's waaay too many parameters imo.

and WATCH OUT for SQL-injections! Read about that

Comment: @MaggiQall could you possibly give me any recommended readings on the best ways to use a class and how to avoid sql injections? Would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `addProfile()` to:

```
function addProfile($post) {

    // Here check wether you have certain post array key set and add it to query

}
```

and use it as :

```
if(isset($_POST['profile_name'])) {

      addProfile($_POST);

}
```

Comment: I'll test it out right now, although that looks like it's exactly what I'll need. Thanks a TON! =]

Comment: I'm still getting the undefined variable notice. Any ideas?